# Is it possible to use environment variables in Create React App manifest.json?

Tags: json, environment-variables, create-react-app

Is it possible to inject environment variables from create-react-app into manifest.json?

I have `REACT_APP_TITLE=title` in my `.env` file and it works injecting it into html as so: `%REACT_APP_TITLE%`, it also works in javascript as so: `process.env.REACT_APP_TITLE`, however, I can't seem to get it to be added to manifest.json (I also tried:

```
{
  "short_name": "REACT_APP_TITLE",
..
``
```

Comment: All of the places you can access them are covered in https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables.

Comment: I guess JSON files not being mentioned means it isn't possible @jonrsharpe , I might need to submit a pull request on their repo if I want to get this working ;)